# Painless tips to work with MS word after using LaTeX during the past 7 years

Tags: msword, latex-to-word

I have used LaTeX during the past 7 years and I have forgotten all about MS Word. Now I need to start using MS Word for my job (and exclusively, no LaTeX).

Have you been in similar positions? what are some tips to do the same stuff in MS Word without going crazy and loosing my patience?

Maybe you master both typesetting systems and would like to share hints and aids for this desperate.

Comment: If this isn't put on hold for being off-topic, it'll probably be closed for being too broad.. :p

Comment: I recommend talking to your boss and convincing him that Word is inferior. If that doesn't help don't try to do the same stuff in Word (or learn to write Word macros and then still don't try to do the same stuff).

Comment: @Skillmon plenty of places it's not your boss who had to get involved with decisions about what software to permit/support. I've known places where you'd have to convince the head of division that it was worth pushing for. There may also be valid interoperability reasons (e.g. all documents must be editable by everyone in the company) which may also conflict with custom macros.

Comment: For new documents, write as markdown and save the documents in plain text to convert secretly to ODT with pandoc, or write secretly  in a plain text editor like Ghostwriter that export markdown to Word, HTML or ODT. The idea is stick to the simplest but still consistent document structure that can be converted anytime without problems  to a Word compatible format. For already made .docx documents from others, bad luck ...consider the cost of the inverse process, or sanitize them in Libreoffice or Abiword, ... against the cost of take the taste to Word.

Comment: The answer is very simple: Get the MS Word manual/documentation and start reading. Once you finished and remember what you read, you will produce proper documents.

Comment: Alternative: Hit the keyboard a few times with a bit of effing and feffing while your boss walks by. If he asks what's up, convince him to use the much *simpler* LaTeX.

Answer (score 1):

Biggest tip, and an easy one if you're used to LaTeX or even html: use styles properly rather than formatting commands.

If you use citations and cross references, use named references until the final version (e.g. "see figure fig_system_layout"), and put "fig_system_layout" in the caption to that figure. You may want to make sure that anything like this that you use fails a spell check.

I'm a little out of date on word so you may need to adapt this: when creating a figure, create a drawing canvas (if that's still the term they use), add something (like a placeholder caption) then import the figure into the canvas. This will stop the caption escaping. Last time I tried there was an official solution to this but that didn't work as well.

Comment: Yesterday I read a book out of boredom "Word 2013 for dummies". And after my 20 min lecture I can say: You're absolutely right. Styles seem to be the only way Word becomes usable.